# Ubuntu shuts down randomly and takes time to restart

Tags: 14.04

Ubuntu shuts down randomly. On restart I see the hd light but monitor is off. Computer is able to restart after about 30mins. 
I don't see any useful information in logs sylog,dmesg etc.

I am using a desktop computer. Around 2 years old.

```
 *-firmware              
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: F1
       date: 10/28/2015
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 8128KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 3d
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 64KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 3e
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 64KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:2
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 3f
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:3
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 40
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 3MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 42
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: KHX2133C14D4/8G
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 0
          serial: 20321324
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:2
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 2
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
     *-bank:3
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 3
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: Sunrise Point-H PMC
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 31
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: bus_master
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df124000-df127fff
```

grep -i mem /var/log/syslog*

```
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009c7ff] usable
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009c800-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000086858fff] usable
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000086859000-0x0000000086859fff] ACPI NVS
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000008685a000-0x0000000086883fff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000086884000-0x00000000868d8fff] usable
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000868d9000-0x0000000086d54fff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000086d55000-0x0000000086d6afff] usable
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000086d6b000-0x00000000879bffff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000879c0000-0x0000000087f99fff] ACPI NVS
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000087f9a000-0x0000000087fccfff] ACPI data
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000087fcd000-0x0000000087ffffff] usable
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000088000000-0x00000000880fffff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e0000000-0x00000000efffffff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe000000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x0000000271ffffff] usable
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000fcab0-0x000fcabf] mapped at [ffff8800000fcab0]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] Base memory trampoline at [ffff880000096000] 96000 size 24576
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] RAMDISK: [mem 0x336d4000-0x35b61fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000271ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] NODE_DATA(0) allocated [mem 0x271ff9000-0x271ffdfff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x00000000ffffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x0000000271ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009bfff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000086858fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000086884000-0x00000000868d8fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000086d55000-0x0000000086d6afff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000087fcd000-0x0000000087ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x0000000271ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000271ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA zone: 64 pages used for memmap
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA32 zone: 8548 pages used for memmap
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   Normal zone: 23680 pages used for memmap
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] Reserving Intel graphics stolen memory at 0x89000000-0x8cffffff
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009c000-0x0009cfff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009d000-0x0009ffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000dffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000e0000-0x000fffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x86859000-0x86859fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x8685a000-0x86883fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x868d9000-0x86d54fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x86d6b000-0x879bffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x879c0000-0x87f99fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x87f9a000-0x87fccfff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x88000000-0x880fffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x88100000-0x88ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x89000000-0x8cffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x8d000000-0xdfffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf0000000-0xfdffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfe000000-0xfe010fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfe011000-0xfebfffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec00000-0xfec00fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec01000-0xfedfffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfee00fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee01000-0xfeffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xff000000-0xffffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] e820: [mem 0x8d000000-0xdfffffff] available for PCI devices
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] Memory: 8012360K/8266312K available (8474K kernel code, 1294K rwdata, 3984K rodata, 1488K init, 1316K bss, 253952K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.026160] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.027399] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 32K (ffffffff820b9000 - ffffffff820c1000)
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.095962] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x86859000-0x86859fff] (4096 bytes)
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.095963] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x879c0000-0x87f99fff] (6135808 bytes)
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.118601] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-ff] at [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] (base 0xe0000000)
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.118603] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] reserved in E820
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.162542] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.162543] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x8d000000-0xdfffffff window]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.162544] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xfd000000-0xfe7fffff window]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.162749] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xde000000-0xdeffffff 64bit]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.162753] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff 64bit pref]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.162913] pci 0000:00:14.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xdf110000-0xdf11ffff 64bit]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.163078] pci 0000:00:14.2: reg 0x10: [mem 0xdf12e000-0xdf12efff 64bit]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.163223] pci 0000:00:16.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xdf12d000-0xdf12dfff 64bit]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.163396] pci 0000:00:17.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xdf128000-0xdf129fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.163403] pci 0000:00:17.0: reg 0x14: [mem 0xdf12c000-0xdf12c0ff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.163428] pci 0000:00:17.0: reg 0x24: [mem 0xdf12b000-0xdf12b7ff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.164062] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x10: [mem 0xdf124000-0xdf127fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.164217] pci 0000:00:1f.3: reg 0x10: [mem 0xdf120000-0xdf123fff 64bit]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.164247] pci 0000:00:1f.3: reg 0x20: [mem 0xdf100000-0xdf10ffff 64bit]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.164454] pci 0000:00:1f.4: reg 0x10: [mem 0xdf12a000-0xdf12a0ff 64bit]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.164790] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xdf000000-0xdf000fff 64bit]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.164805] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0xd0000000-0xd0003fff 64bit pref]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.174501] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0xdf000000-0xdf0fffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.174511] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd00fffff 64bit pref]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.176198] vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:00:02.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.204634] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x0009c800-0x0009ffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.204635] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x86859000-0x87ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.204636] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x868d9000-0x87ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.204637] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x86d6b000-0x87ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.204638] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x272000000-0x273ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210956] system 00:06: [mem 0xfed10000-0xfed17fff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210958] system 00:06: [mem 0xfed18000-0xfed18fff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210958] system 00:06: [mem 0xfed19000-0xfed19fff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210959] system 00:06: [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210960] system 00:06: [mem 0xfed20000-0xfed3ffff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210961] system 00:06: [mem 0xfed90000-0xfed93fff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210962] system 00:06: [mem 0xfed45000-0xfed8ffff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210963] system 00:06: [mem 0xff000000-0xffffffff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210964] system 00:06: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfeefffff] could not be reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210965] system 00:06: [mem 0xdffe0000-0xdfffffff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210989] system 00:07: [mem 0xfd000000-0xfdabffff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210990] system 00:07: [mem 0xfdad0000-0xfdadffff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210991] system 00:07: [mem 0xfdb00000-0xfdffffff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210993] system 00:07: [mem 0xfe000000-0xfe01ffff] could not be reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210994] system 00:07: [mem 0xfe036000-0xfe03bfff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210995] system 00:07: [mem 0xfe03d000-0xfe3fffff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.210996] system 00:07: [mem 0xfe410000-0xfe7fffff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.211586] system 00:08: [mem 0xfdaf0000-0xfdafffff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.211587] system 00:08: [mem 0xfdae0000-0xfdaeffff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.211588] system 00:08: [mem 0xfdac0000-0xfdacffff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.219955] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0xdf000000-0xdf0fffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.219957] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd00fffff 64bit pref]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.219970] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 6 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.219971] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 7 [mem 0x8d000000-0xdfffffff window]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.219972] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 8 [mem 0xfd000000-0xfe7fffff window]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.219974] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 1 [mem 0xdf000000-0xdf0fffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.219975] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 2 [mem 0xd0000000-0xd00fffff 64bit pref]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.579988] Freeing initrd memory: 37432K (ffff8800336d4000 - ffff880035b62000)
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.580024] software IO TLB [mem 0x82859000-0x86859000] (64MB) mapped at [ffff880082859000-ffff880086858fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.580176] Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.606377] memory memory33: hash matches
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.607518] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1488K (ffffffff81f45000 - ffffffff820b9000)
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.607946] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1752K (ffff88000184a000 - ffff880001a00000)
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.608167] Freeing unused kernel memory: 112K (ffff880001de4000 - ffff880001e00000)
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.701405] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 4096M
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:03 Parshi kernel: [    0.720522] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 20:30:44 Parshi org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor[1700]: Volume monitor alive
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009c7ff] usable
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009c800-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000086858fff] usable
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000086859000-0x0000000086859fff] ACPI NVS
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000008685a000-0x0000000086883fff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000086884000-0x00000000868d8fff] usable
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000868d9000-0x0000000086d54fff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000086d55000-0x0000000086d6afff] usable
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000086d6b000-0x00000000879bffff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000879c0000-0x0000000087f99fff] ACPI NVS
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000087f9a000-0x0000000087fccfff] ACPI data
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000087fcd000-0x0000000087ffffff] usable
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000088000000-0x00000000880fffff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e0000000-0x00000000efffffff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe000000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x0000000271ffffff] usable
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000fcab0-0x000fcabf] mapped at [ffff8800000fcab0]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] Base memory trampoline at [ffff880000096000] 96000 size 24576
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] RAMDISK: [mem 0x336d4000-0x35b61fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000271ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] NODE_DATA(0) allocated [mem 0x271ff9000-0x271ffdfff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x00000000ffffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x0000000271ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009bfff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000086858fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000086884000-0x00000000868d8fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000086d55000-0x0000000086d6afff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000087fcd000-0x0000000087ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x0000000271ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000271ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA zone: 64 pages used for memmap
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA32 zone: 8548 pages used for memmap
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000]   Normal zone: 23680 pages used for memmap
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] Reserving Intel graphics stolen memory at 0x89000000-0x8cffffff
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009c000-0x0009cfff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009d000-0x0009ffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000dffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000e0000-0x000fffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x86859000-0x86859fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x8685a000-0x86883fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x868d9000-0x86d54fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x86d6b000-0x879bffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x879c0000-0x87f99fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x87f9a000-0x87fccfff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x88000000-0x880fffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x88100000-0x88ffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x89000000-0x8cffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x8d000000-0xdfffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf0000000-0xfdffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfe000000-0xfe010fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfe011000-0xfebfffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec00000-0xfec00fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec01000-0xfedfffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfee00fff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee01000-0xfeffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xff000000-0xffffffff]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] e820: [mem 0x8d000000-0xdfffffff] available for PCI devices
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.000000] Memory: 8012360K/8266312K available (8474K kernel code, 1294K rwdata, 3984K rodata, 1488K init, 1316K bss, 253952K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.026301] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.027550] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 32K (ffffffff820b9000 - ffffffff820c1000)
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.096175] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x86859000-0x86859fff] (4096 bytes)
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.096175] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x879c0000-0x87f99fff] (6135808 bytes)
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.122802] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-ff] at [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] (base 0xe0000000)
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.122803] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] reserved in E820
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.162709] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.162709] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x8d000000-0xdfffffff window]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.162710] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xfd000000-0xfe7fffff window]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.162915] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xde000000-0xdeffffff 64bit]
/var/log/syslog:Aug 13 23:16:43 Parshi kernel: [    0.162919] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff 64bit pref]
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `grep -i -e temp -e therm /var/log/syslog*` and I'll take a look. Is this a laptop or desktop? How old?

Comment: @heynnema on few occasions on restart the system light is on but monitor light is off

Comment: Is this a laptop or desktop? If desktop, does your video card have a fan on it? If so, is it working? When you say that the video monitor light is off, do you mean the power light? Is this the same light that indicates that it's in energy saving mode? What color is the light? What kind of video card?

Comment: It's a desktop. Does not have a video card, built in. Monitor light is same as when system is off(orange, blue when it's on).

Comment: Just to confirm... the video is built into the motherboard... sometimes the light on the monitor is off... not orange and not blue,,, but off. Why can't the computer be rebooted before 30 minutes? Have you checked to make sure that you have the latest BIOS in your motherboard? How much RAM? Lets look at `grep -i mem /var/log/syslog*` and `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: Was trying to get into bios just now. The bios entry key was incorrect the first time, hence I restarted. Now have the same issue, system light is on(blue) but monitor is offf. Maybe hardware issue not related to thermal?

Comment: Yes, that's why I started asking about memory. See my last comment.

Comment: output of lshw -C memory and grep -i mem /var/log/syslog added to comment. Had to restrict the output due to max limit of comment size.

Comment: So far I haven't seen anything in syslog that concerns me. However, lets run a memory test. Go to http://memtest86.org and download their free memory diagnostic and run it at least one full pass. Report back.

Comment: Running memtest on boot passes. No errors. Maybe smps issue?

Comment: Reset the power manager by shutting down the system, pull the AC power cord, press and hold the power button for 10 seconds, you'll notice the fans move, reconnect AC power cord, boot.

Comment: No difference. I would be taking it to service.